# Workbox not Overriding Default Strategy

Tags: nuxt.js, workbox

Having some issues overriding the default cacheFirst strategy in Nuxt Workbox.

Expected behavior: cacheFirst is replaced by staleWhileRevalidate

nuxt.config.js:

```
workbox: {
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: '/_nuxt/.*',
      handler: 'staleWhileRevalidate',
      method: 'GET'
    }
  ]
}
```

Current behavior: Creates a new entry instead of overriding.

sw.js:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/_nuxt/.*'),
workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({}), 'GET')

workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/.*'), 
workbox.strategies.networkFirst({}), 'GET')

workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/_nuxt/.*'), 
workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({}), 'GET')
```

Not sure what I am missing. Thank  you for the help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to have sort of resolved this by adding to nuxt.config.js:

```
workbox: {
  cachingExtensions: '@/plugins/wb-ext.js'
}
```

Then my wb-ext.js contains:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/_nuxt/.*'), 
workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
  plugins: [
    new workbox.broadcastUpdate.Plugin('new-update-channel')
  ]
}), 'GET')
```

This adds the wb-ext code above the auto generated cacheFirst strategy created by Nuxt Workbox in the sw.js file.

Now during Dev, I get a message stating Workbox is using StaleWhileRevalidate in the Dev Console, and the broadcast update plugin works as expected.

Feel free to comment if you have a cleaner way of achieving this without having conflicting strategies in the sw.js file.

Thank you!